# When I walk down the stairs where does my potential energy go?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, biology, dissipation

When I leave my room I walk down three flights of stairs releasing about 7kJ of potential energy. Where does it go? Is it all getting dispersed into heat and sound? Is that heat being generated at the point of impact between my feet and the ground, or is it within my muscles?

Related question, how much energy do I consume by walking? Obviously there's the work I'm doing against air resistance, but I feel like that doesn't account for all the energy I use when walking.

Comment: Speeding up the earths rotation, crazy as it sounds...

Comment: Only if you're walking to the west.

Comment: @StianYttervik I assume you're talking about the speedup due to reducing the Earth's moment of inertia. That is only a very small part of the energy. It is purely an effect of rotational dynamics and has nothing to do with the Earth's gravity, so its magnitude is unrelated to that of the potential energy loss. Rather, it scales with the centripetal acceleration of the Earth's surface, which is at most 0.3% of $g$.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The effect of horizontal (tangential) motion on the Earth's rotational speed lasts only during the motion itself; there is no permanent change. Stian Yttervik was presumably talking about the effect of *vertical* (radial) motion, which would occur even if descending say a firefighter's pole instead of stairs. This is a genuine, permanent, but very small effect, per my comment above.

Comment: @nanoman all other energy is dissipated to non elastic effects and heat. Rotation of earth is not only the coolest effect, it is also a reversible energy transfer.

Comment: If you have another question, no matter how related you think it is, you should pose it as a separate question

Comment: @StianYttervik or slowing down or neither depending on which direction you are going.

Comment: You potential energy goes down just like you do.

Comment: @StianYttervik That's not the gravitational potential energy, though (in the case of going down stairs or a pole, etc) - that's just your angular momentum doing that (which is a form of kinetic energy, not potential).  The gravitational energy is dissipated by various mechanisms.

Comment: @J... Angular momentum is _not_ a form of kinetic energy.

Comment: @my2cts Quite right, poor choice of words - angular momentum is directly related to kinetic energy, however, which was what I was getting at.  It's entirely to do with your angular velocity while riding on a spinning earth.  If the Earth (and, by extension you) did not rotate then simply going down a pole would not cause it to start rotating.  If the Earth and person are rotating, however, then going down a pole changes the moment of inertia of the earth and its angular velocity will change to conserve angular momentum of the system.

Comment: Just in passing.  Start a little higher up (say 10 stories).  Run down the stairs as fast as you can, taking the steps two at a time.  If you are giving up energy, why are you out of breath?  Real life is more complicated that the equations in introductory Mechanics books

Comment: @Flydog57 This is because every action has a reaction, you have kinetic energy and you are transferring it somewhere, effectively exerting a force in a direction, by definition there is an opposing force on your body every time you step foot (think of it as bouncing), which your muscles need to dissipate to stabilize your body, hence why you're tired. This force is also present at rest and slightly smaller, it's the counteraction of gravity. Otherwise you'd just be a blob of flesh, flat on the ground

Comment: @Tofandel: That was my point. Thanks!

Comment: @nanoman Does going upstairs accelerate Earth's rotation, then?

Comment: @StianYttervik Yes, that sounds crazy that we are helping to move the earth rotate by walking.

Comment: @StianYttervik I have joined the community just to upvote your first comment )

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The heat is predominantly generated in your muscles.

More direct conversion of potential energy to heat is when a person is sliding down a pole to get to a lower floor quickly. With sufficient friction, the descent is at a constant velocity instead of accelerating.

In muscle, some structures slide along each other. Muscle contraction is those structures being made to move relative to each other, using molecular motors that act somewhat like a hand-over-hand method.

As we know, muscles can also extend in a controlled manner. If you are bending down to the ground you allow your muscles to extend while maintaining tension, so that your motion is controlled.

During that controlled extending: potential energy converts to heat in the muscles.

This conversion of potential energy is on top of the baseline heat generation because the muscle is *active*.

When you stand up your muscles are working against gravity, actively contracting. The energy source for that contraction is, ultimately, the food you have eaten.  In the muscles, the conversion of chemical energy is not 100% efficient. A percentage is transformed to actual power output, a percentage becomes heat straightaway.

When you are allowing your muscles to extend in a controlled manner your muscles are *active*, so some heat is generated just because the muscle is active.

When you are walking downstairs the total heat generated in the muscles is the sum of two contributions: heat that is generated anyway because the muscle is active, and heat generated because the process of a muscle being extended *against muscle tension* is work being done *on* the muscle, and that leads to heat generation in the muscle. (That is, that heat is *not*  generated in the muscle when a completely *relaxed* muscle is extended by an external force.)

In walking we use our leg muscles actively to smooth out the motion; the leg muscles are used actively to provide some level of *elastic suspension*.

By comparison, kangaroos are known to have Achilles tendons that are optimized to store elastic energy. The jumping form of travelling that kangaroos can do is quite energy-efficient. The power needed for the next jump is mostly from elastic energy stored in the tendon on coming down.

Human walking doesn't have that level of efficiency. Muscle power is used *actively* both when the centre of mass of the body comes down and when the centre of mass of the body comes back up again. So there is the generation of heat from that power output.

Comment: As a child I felt it really unfair that walking downstairs costs effort. I thought it ought to be giving you more energy, making you less tired. There must be a better way. :-)

Comment: @RedSonja while I can't claim going down a long fast slide gives you physical energy, it certainly brightens up your day for some metaphorical energy.  All tall buildings should have them

Comment: @ChrisH The artist Carsten Höller might agree with you.

Comment: @RedSonja to this day it annoys me greatly that basically all electrified mountainbikes fail to make use of the possibility of _regerative braking_ (unlike electric cars, which use this to significantly extend their range in mountainous trips).

Comment: @RedSonja The energy currency of the body as a whole, hence of muscle cells too, is the ATP molecule. Muscle fiber contraction consumes ATP.  From a molecular physics point of view: I think it is possible to have a reverse version of the muscle contraction process: A molecular structure (in the muscle) such that when work is done on it, stretching it, ATP is generated. The snag: while molecularly possible, circumstances where such an ability is worth it will be so rare: I don't think any species will ever be in a position to evolve it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Link to: bicycle stackexchange [Why are regenerative brakes uncommon on e-bikes?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/71598)

Comment: @Cleonis yes, and particularly [my answer there](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/71619/3039), arguing why and in which situations it _would_ make sense.

Comment: I once walked part of the way down into the grand canyon and then back up.  The walk down was far more strenuous for me and we did the return trip took maybe a third of the time that it took to walk down.

Answer (score 150):

Make it simple. If a mass of your weight fell down  the height of  three flights of stairs through the air, when it landed where would the kinetic energy accumulated by falling go?

1. moving the earth for  conservation of momentum
2. dissipated in heat on the ground
3. deformation of the matter of the weight
4. sound

That is why humans invented the stairs, to dissipate the kinetic energy acquired in small increments, in the same but in a  non-human-frame-destructive way.

Comment: "to dissipate the kinetic energy acquired in small increments".  This is the key.

Comment: Note, the energy of #1 is negligibly small compared to the others because of the huge mass of the Earth.

Comment: @nanoman sure, but I like reminding that momentum conservation is a law too.

Comment: And Phonons too

Comment: @nanoman the huge mass of the Earth doesn't prove anything about the proportion of energy dissipated by momentum transfer. It only means that an absolutely tiny change in velocity is necessary to transfer 100% of your kinetic energy. In practice, the earth isn't nearly rigid enough for its whole mass to be relevant. Energy forms 1, 2, and 4 are essentially all localised descriptions of the same lossy momentum transfer from the impact site to the surroundings.

Comment: @Will No, nanoman is right. What *is* transferred in significant quantities is momentum, which is $F*t$; the kinetic energy though is almost entirely transformed into heat because it is $F*s$, and the Earth (if we consider it an inertial system for the split second of the impact) doesn't move *at all*, so that the distance over which the force is applied to Earth is practically zero, and with it the transferred kinetic energy. Unfortunately anna has confused the issue by making the momentum change the first answer of the question "where does the energy go?" The two are unrelated.

Comment: @Will A related phenomenon concerns rocket drives. If the mass expelled by a rocket motor is very small -- as in an ion or photon drive --, almost all kinetic energy is in the exhaust, even if the *momentum* is of course, as always, equally divided. That's why we need so much reaction mass on rockets. (An ion drive still makes sense because with solar sails or nuclear power energy is long-term available, but mass always is a more finite resource.)

Comment: You may want to correct the conflation of momentum with energy in number 1; it is "not even wrong". Also note that the momentum transferred to the Earth upon impact is the exact inverse of the momentum the Earth gained while the body was falling, accelerating the Earth towards itself. After all, the center of mass during the entire incident never moved.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica  given the mass and the velocity one can get both the energy and the momentum. There can be no momentum without kinetic energy.(classical mechanics)

Comment: @annav, I like it how you phrased:  "That is why humans invented the stairs, to dissipate the kinetic energy acquired in small increments, in the same but in a non-human-frame-destructive way."  That's a clever way of putting it, even if it *does* give the impression that Isaac Newton pre-dated the invention of stairs.

Comment: Yes, there can be no momentum without kinetic energy, true; but in the case of collisions of vastly different masses there is no significant kinetic energy transfer. All the energy stays with the smaller body in elastic collisions or is transformed to heat in non-elastic ones (as in the example here). Don't you agree with that? It's like "there is no current without a field" but of course there can be a field with almost no current.

Comment: @RonJohn I bet that was exactly what they were thinking when they invented stairs too!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica sure, that why I start with "make is simple", in order  not to go into all that

Comment: Everything said in this answer is correct, but the answer to the question is "it goes to heat in your muscles", which surprisingly isn't mentioned here at all.

Comment: @MattTimmermans  It is because of "make it simple". It is covered within the "deformation of the matter of the weight" . An inanimate sack will deform the energy going  eventually into heat and permanent deformation.  An animate one has ways of keeping its form by absorbing the energy into the muscles, the muscles emitting extra energy etc, not simple but efficient in keeping the integrity of the animal  if the increments of potential energy to kinetic are small.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, once you are standing still at the bottom of the stairs then all of the potential energy you had at the top of the stairs has been transformed into heat (due to friction and heat produced by your body) and sound waves. And even the energy in the sound waves ends up as heat once it has been absorbed by the walls, floor, ceiling etc.

Answer (score 9):

The potential energy of your body starting at a height is gradually lost with each step.

Your body is transferring this potential energy into the stretching and flexing of your muscles, and the heat created by this. Some of the energy is also lost due to friction from your feet or shoes in contact with the stairs, some is lost to air resistance and sound.

Basically, a majority of the potential energy is gradually lost to biological and biochemical processes (generating heat).

Answer (score 3):

As you take a step, you accelerate for a short while, before coming to rest again. Then you step down further. This way you cyclically reduce yourself from a higher level(energy or otherwise) to a lower one in steps, no pun intended.

At the end of each step, you come to an abrupt stop. That's because you suffer an inelastic collision with the step. The step exerts a force on you upon contact, stopping you. Since you don't bounce, the collision is inelastic.

The resulting energy loss could be to the ground (stiff stairs) or be shock absorbed and dissipated in your legs (steep stairs), go into silent deformation (soft stairs), be eaten up by friction (wide & rough stairs) or be lost as expletives (thorny stairs)!.

As mentioned in other answers, if you are the system, the earth is the surroundings. So if you lose energy, the earth gains it.

> how much energy do I consume by walking?

You rightly conjectured that at a walking pace, the loss to air drag is negligible. So what is the work being done against? It's actually to again accelerate you forth. As one walks, one pushes against the ground gaining energy, then losses some on re-impact on the following step. There's definitely energy being lost, so it must be supplied. The exact kinematics or biomechanics aren't easy to model. As a rough estimate, if you are moving with speed $v$ and in each step, you generate, again grossly speaking, an average force of $F$, then your walking is dissipating energy at the rate $Fv$.

---

Footnote: The above discussion of energy loss via inelastic collision is, like many other answers, a simplified view. As I remarked the actual biomechanics of walking or going down steps are more refined and evolved. In particular, in the case of stepping downstairs, our body has learned to slow itself right before landing. We step gently not abruptly. To achieve this, our muscles do work by extending/contracting to exert control - that takes a lot of work too. See [Cleonis's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/645232/226560) above for that perspective.

Comment: What you're describing here is _stomping_ down a stairset. It is not advisable – very loud, especially on wooden stairs, and quite bad for the joints. A proper way to descent actually involves “braking”, both before you hit the next step, and while setting down the foot (toes first, then softly put down the heel).

Comment: @leftaroundabout yeah I had thought about, mentitoning that but I made the *cow to be a sphere*

Comment: @leftaroundabout *A proper way to descent...* i think its  the natural way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice answer by @annav, I would like to add something none of the answers mention, that is atmospheric pressure.

However small the atmospheric pressure is changing when you walk down the stars, it does change, and it means that as you descend, your body must take more pressure.

> At low altitudes above sea level, the pressure decreases by about 1.2 kPa (12 hPa) for every 100 metres.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure

As the atmospheric pressure rises (when you walk down the stairs), your body needs to act against it (so your body needs to adjust accordingly), and this needs energy from the body.

Answer (score 0):

Potential energy and kinetic energy constantly convert between each other. The conversion is not perfect as some energy is dissipated into friction and deformation of materials.

When going down stairs, your brain has learnt to let your body fall in a controlled manner. How? If you move your body horizontally beyond the edge of the step, you can decrease the force you apply in the leg still in contact with the ground and gravity will accelerate your body downwards. Your potential energy is almost entirely converted to kinetic energy during that acceleration. As your forward foot reaches the step below, it must slow down your body, ie generate a force opposite to gravity. This uses energy stored in our cells. If you stop on that next step, then you've had to dissipate the kinetic energy you've converted from potential energy. It dissipates into your body almost entirely, with very small amount in friction between floor and feet. The dissipation is in heat and friction. The friction causes heat but also atoms to get dislodged ie nanoscopic damage to your tissues, and some of the energy goes there. Your tissues heal in due course.

That's why bigger steps are uncomfortable, the energy to dissipate increases quickly with step height. And that's why going down a thousand steps in a controlled manner is actually very demanding on your body, you've caused a noticeable amount of wear on your body and heat in your muscles. If you get rest, you will convert energy from food into repairing your tissues (muscles, cartilage, ligaments etc) so they are ready for the next flight of stairs - and most likely to go up it!).

Our brains learn how to optimize the motion when we go down many steps in sequence, so we have less energy to dissipate: we don't need to completely stop our body at each step, so we apply just enough force for the net acceleration to be zero, and our motion is as near constant speed down the flight of stairs as we are able. We've learnt to change this counter force constantly as we move down from one step to the next.

Go ahead, try going down a flight of steps but completely stop your body at each step. Remember to alternate which foot goes down at each step.

Answer (score -1):

This is easily tested experimentally. If you walked down a longer staircase, such as subway escalator, as fast as possible, you would feel that most of the energy have been be dissipated as heat in shin muscles and tendons. Then it rapidly moves with blood flow into the rest of your body.

Energy consumption for 5km/h walking is 4 calories per kilometer per kilogram of weight.

Comment: I have never noticed my legs being hot after descending a long staircase. Even dissipating 10kJ of energy entirely as heat, you'd only warm 10kg of water (a reasonable approximation of two legs from the knee down) by about a tenth of a degree C. This isn't something you'd notice experimentally without specialized equipment.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie That's if you imply that it warms up uniformly, but it doesn't. Most of the heat goes into back lower part.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie muscles aren't perfectly efficient, nor is walking (not all of the energy expended in walking down stairs is attributable to the person's loss of potential energy).

Answer (score -2):

#### Into the motion of your body.

When you go down the stairs, your muscles take the vertical motion down the stairs and add a horizontal component to it. As you travel down the stairs, you will be accelerated vertically by gravity, as your potential energy is converted into kinetic energy. The faster you go vertically, the faster you go horizontally, so unless you deliberately slow yourself down, you're going a lot faster horizontally at the bottom of the stairs than you were at the top of them. As a result, in addition to the conversions into heat and sound energy covered by other answers, a portion of the potential energy you possessed at the top of the stairs has been converted into kinetic energy.

Comment: People often stand still for a moment after descending a flight of stairs - I think it's best to assume that that's the situation. It's certainly not typical to continuously accelerate while descending stairs - that would be known as falling rather than descending.

Comment: @bdsl Have you ever gone down a flight of stairs without slowing yourself down? You do continuously accelerate unless your legs are exerting a force to slow yourself down.

Comment: I have - I call it falling down the stairs. My point is that when using stairs normally slowing yourself down is so integral to the process that it doesn't make sense to separate it out and consider not doing it.

Comment: @bdsl Nope, not falling, you're in control, you're just loosening your legs so that you're not slowing yourself down. I did it all the time as a kid.

Comment: When you did that descending a series of 12 steps you reached the bottom at some typical speed. If you descended 24 steps in the same way did you end up going twice as fast? I think that's very unlikely, and you were in fact absorbing the energy within your legs as you went, albeit rapidly.

Comment: You might move faster on the stairs than level walking, but you certainly aren't constantly accelerated, or you'd *continually* speed up every step. You probably reach a new faster speed after a few steps, then its back to cushioning against gravity to maintain constant (ish) speed. At the bottom you return to.level walking - probably similar gait as before, so you bleed off that kinetic energy in a few steps as well, back to low level heat. Technically whether you see that as part of descending the steps, or separate, is a personal choice.

Comment: Yes, you can accelerate while going down stairs, but you don't leave a flight of stairs in a full sprint. The kinetic energy gained when descending even a 5m tall staircase would be nearly enough *to break the human footspeed record* - the majority of that energy is clearly going somewhere else.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie "you don't leave a flight of stairs in a full sprint" When you don't slow yourself down, as I've described, you actually do.

Comment: @bdsl at a constant acceleration, velocity is proportional to the square root of the distance, so after descending 24 steps under constant acceleration one would be going just over 40% faster than one was at the 12th step.

Comment: @phoog You're right, I forgot that energy is proportional to speed squared.

Comment: @nick012000 You are describing a *slide*, not a set of stairs. It is literally impossible to descend a set of stairs *without* slowing yourself down.